# I get the error "usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110"

Tags: linux, usb, mount

When trying to mount the sdcard from my android tablet under linux I get the following error in `dmesg`:

```
usb 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110
```

The card doesn't show under lsusb or lsscsi. So it can't be mounted. I can boot into windoze and it mounts fine it also works fine in the android tablet. All other USB devices mount fine, it is just the sdcard that isn't seen properly. I am using Linux version 3.2.29-smp. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back to answer my own question.

I discovered that completely shutting down the computer and UNPLUGGING FOR A MINUTE solves this problem. It had something to do with the bios being corrupted. Unplugging the cord cleared the error.  Who'd a known, eh?

It seems even though you turn the computer off the mother board still has power applied to it for quick bootup. The only way to clear all data from the bios is to kill all power to the mother board, so unplugging is the answer. Viola!

Comment: That's unlikely the reason. Any recent computer is going to have an EFI/UEFI firmware that uses non volatile memory and even older ones with an actual CMOS memory had a battery.  So you won't be clearing all the firmware settings by unpluggin the power cord, there's usually a jumper on the motherboard for that task. It can be still some electrical issue resolving on its own while main power is removed.